# Angular Js RouteProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using $routeProvider service in my angular js but problem is on templateURl it provides me error

from server here is the error what i received

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
angular.js:11594 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /Testing/TestCompleted

and here is my angular code for app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('CreateController', CreateController);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        templateUrl: "/Testing/TestCompleted",
        controller:"AppCtrl"
    })
});
app.controller("AppCtrl",function ($scope) {
    $scope.newmodel = {

    }
});
```

Comment: It means that you don't have such URL  /Testing/TestCompleted

Comment: What do you see if you just try to view that one template in a browser? For example, if your main app is at http://example.com/myDir/myApp/index.html, what happens if you load up http://example.com/Testing/TestCompleted ?) If you can resolve that address and it doesn't throw an error, your angular code should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution the view is only returned by server by using route we can only get html view not cshtml because that is provided when action is called.

Answer (score 0):

The url is giving a ERROR 500. This is that there is something wrong in de code of the page. Please attach your debugger and go to the url "/Testing/TestCompleted" with a browser and check what is wrong.

**Edit:**

If the url is really the right one. Please try the following:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .controller("AppCtrl",function ($scope) {
    $scope.newmodel = {}
  })
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        templateUrl: "/Testing/TestCompleted",
        controller:"AppCtrl"
    })
});
```

So that the controller is registerd before you do your config as in the example from Angular (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

Comment: no there is wno error the error is in my js that i am not sending the correct url please tell me what is the way of correct url

Answer (score 0):

The address of the template is likely wrong. I never had to use a format such as '/....' .
You probably want 'Testing/TestCompleted' if the directory Testing is at the root of your project (or './Testing/TestCompleted' both should work).

EDIT:

In any case you are probably using an html file for the template, with an extension .html . So use 'Testing/TestCompleted.html' for instance.

Comment: / in the beginning means that it will request from the base url, that is not the problem

Comment: @Patrick I never used this syntax so I thought it would not work, thanks for the information. My second suggestion is still valid though, he should put the html extension.

Comment: Of course that's just a guess. Considering the OP gets a 500 Internal Server Error and not a 404 Not found I would guess that there's a problem with the handler and not that the file exists or not on the server.

Comment: @Patrick I agree that if the problem was a missing a file the code would not be 500 but Not Found (don't remember the name)

Comment: i used .html file that is working but i need to get the file of .cshtml how to get this

Comment: You mean a file with .cshtml extension ? it needs to be compiled first so you need to check the structure generated by your application and find where the .html file is placed . you can find out by interogating the root of your app from the browser when it is running. You should be able to browse it.